# Efficiently preventing duplicate accesses

Tags: c++

I have a statement computing a multiply-accumulate operation that looks something like this:

```
return A->set(A->get() + B->get() * C->get());
```

Now, A, B, and C may not be unique, and I want to minimize redundant `get()`s. The only way I can think of optimizing this is with

```
  if (A == B && B == C) {
    double a = A->get();
    return A->set(a + a * a);
  } else if (A == B) {
    double a = A->get();
    return A->set(a + a * C->get());
  } else if (A == C) {
    double a = A->get();
    return A->set(a + B->get() * a);
  } else if (B == C) {
    double b = B->get();
    return A->set(A->get() + b * b);
  } else {
    return A->set(A->get() + B->get() * C->get());
  }
```

Is there a more efficient way? What about generalizing this to more than three arguments??

Comment: Could you jam them into a [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) which forces them to be unique, then fetch the resulting entries? That seems a lot more scalable than this wickedly complicated code that only handles up to three entries.

Comment: I want to minimize redundant `get()`, why though?

Comment: does `get` take long time? otherwise you're just making it worse.

Comment: You could also use a `std::map` to store the `get()` result of any given operation, and then use that as a sort of cache. This is only really important if your `get()` calls are sufficiently expensive and the performance impact of not doing this is severe *and* measurable.

Comment: Explain "more efficient". Do you mean less comparisons in general or less/cleaner code?

Comment: The even more obvious answer here is to make `get()` cache if necessary.

Comment: I was thinking about fewer comparisons and cleaner code, as well as fewer calls to `get()`. The issue is not the actual timing; this is a simulated model of a hardware system, so the call has a significant communication overhead.

Comment: What exactly are `A`, `B`, and `C`? Why are these getters needed to begin with? In particular, why is comparing these objects faster than using `get()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `get()` methods are really costly to the extent of producing measurable performance difference,

```
double a,b,c;
a = A->get();
b = (B==A?a:B->get());
c = (C==B?b:(C==A?a:c->get()));
return A->set(a+b*c);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store them in a map. The solution can be extended easily to arbitrarily many pointers, but I've used three here for concreteness.

```cpp
std::unordered_map<MyType *, double> computed_values;
for (MyType *p: {A, B, C}) {
    if (computed_values.find(p) == computed_values.end()) {
        computed_values[p] = p->get();
    }
}
double result = computed_values[A] + computed_values[B] * computed_values[C];
A->set(result);
```

As others have pointed out, make sure you profile to make sure this is actually worth the overhead of `std::unordered_map` lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the get() methods are reasonably cheap, you'd be better off just doing:

```
return A->set(A->get() + B->get() * C->get());
```

The other approach simply inserts a bunch of conditional jumps into your code, which could easily end up  being more expensive than the original code.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and would be better as a comment in my opinion, or not posted at all. It's just saying "well, maybe you don't need to do what you asked after all!" rather than actually making any progress towards doing what the OP asked.